# View Binding causes "The specified child already has a parent"

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I decided to try the new View Binding feature https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding, but had the app crash whenever I tried to open the Activity using it. This is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I had already needed to do some troubleshooting and finagling of my various build.gradle dependencies to get the app to even compile and run with View Binding, so I tried various troubleshooting steps to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I felt stupid when I realized what the problem was. When I converted the Activity to use View Binding, I didn't realize the layout had a `View` with an `id` of `root`.

Changing the ID of that View solved the problem for me. If you're using View Binding, you cannot use `root` as the ID for any View in your layout, or you will get this unhelpful error.

Comment: This seems worthy of a bug report. They should be able to detect this at compile time and yelp if they can't handle it. Are you in position to file one with a project that reproduces the problem? If not, I can try to file one.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's a good point. I went ahead and filed a bug report at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150455687

Comment: Update: Google isn't interested in fixing it, describing it as an "erroneous pattern" on my part. They might add a note to the documentation, but I wouldn't hold my breath. Hopefully anyone else running into the same issue will arrive at this StackOverflow question so they can quickly resolve their crash.

Comment: Got in exactly same situation. Thanks, your feedback helped to identify the issue!